# Ruby On Rails - Delete element from session variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I've a session variable which is an array:

```
session[:products] ||= []
```

In this variable I save the id's of products which are in the cart and want to remove the id from this array when I delete a product from cart.

I do this for add new id:

```
(session[:products] ||= []) << params[:id]
```

And I try the inverse for remove but doesn't work:

```
(session[:products] ||= []) >> params[:id]
```

Any idea? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply delete element of array with

```
session[:products].delete(params[:id])
```

Comment: I don't want to delete the session key. This session key has an array of id's and I want to delete one of this id's. For exemple: session[:products] || = [1,2,3]